# How to preserve await behavior with TaskCompletionSource.SetException?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, taskcompletionsource

(This is a new attempt at this question which now demonstrates the issue better.)

Let's say we have a faulted task (`var faultedTask = Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("test"); });`) and we await it. `await` will unpack the `AggregateException` and throw the underlying exception. It will throw `faultedTask.Exception.InnerExceptions.First()`.

According to the source code for `ThrowForNonSuccess` it will do this by executing any stored `ExceptionDispatchInfo` presumably to preserve nice stack traces. It will not unpack the `AggregateException` if there is no `ExceptionDispatchInfo`.

This fact alone was surprising to me because the documentation states that the first exception is *always* thrown: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 It turns out that `await` can throw `AggregateException`, though, which is not documented behavior.

This becomes a problem when we want to create a proxy task and set it's exception:

```
var proxyTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
proxyTcs.SetException(faultedTask.Exception);
await proxyTcs.Task;
```

This throws `AggregateException` whereas `await faultedTask;` would have thrown the test exception.

**How can I create a proxy task that I can complete at will and that will mirror the exception behavior that the original task had?**

**The original behavior is:**

1. `await` will throw the first inner exception.
2. All exceptions are still available through `Task.Exception.InnerExceptions`. (An earlier version of this question left out this requirement.)

Here's a test that summarizes the findings:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ExceptionAwait()
{
    ExceptionAwaitAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task ExceptionAwaitAsync()
{
    //Task has multiple exceptions.
    var faultedTask = Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("test"); }), Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("test"); }));

    try
    {
        await faultedTask;
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(ex.Message == "test"); //Works.
    }

    Assert.IsTrue(faultedTask.Exception.InnerExceptions.Count == 2); //Works.

    //Both attempts will fail. Uncomment attempt 1 to try the second one.
    await Attempt1(faultedTask);
    await Attempt2(faultedTask);
}

static async Task Attempt1(Task faultedTask)
{
    var proxyTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    proxyTcs.SetException(faultedTask.Exception);

    try
    {
        await proxyTcs.Task;
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(ex.Message == "test"); //Fails.
    }
}

static async Task Attempt2(Task faultedTask)
{
    var proxyTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    proxyTcs.SetException(faultedTask.Exception.InnerExceptions.First());

    try
    {
        await proxyTcs.Task;
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(ex.Message == "test"); //Works.
    }

    Assert.IsTrue(proxyTcs.Task.Exception.InnerExceptions.Count == 2); //Fails. Should preserve both exceptions.
}
```

The motivation for this question is that I'm trying to construct a function that will copy the result of one task over to a `TaskCompletionSource`. This is a helper function that's used often when writing task combinator functions. It's important that API clients cannot detect the difference between the original task and a proxy task.

Comment: It is always fun to read a new question from a 50k+ rep user, 90% of the time I go "ooh, I'd like to know that too" and end up favoriting the question

Comment: If it's the `await` semantics you want with regards to exceptions, why not just go straight to the source (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs,ca9850c71672bd54) and copy what `TaskAwaiter` does?

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy this uses internal APIs. Also, the caller of my code shouldn't need to know anything special.

Comment: @usr: `I'm trying to construct a function that will copy the result of one task over to a TaskCompletionSource.` Feel free to copy [either](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Tasks/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskCompletionSourceExtensions.cs#L12) of [mine](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/Source/Nito.AsyncEx%20(NET45%2C%20Win8%2C%20WP8%2C%20WPA81)/TaskCompletionSourceExtensions.cs#L14).

Comment: @StephenCleary mine is now modeled in this spirit. Meanwhile, I also reviewed Jon's public code. Apparently, everybody except me knew to use the right overload. Getting every nuance right with TPL code can be a black art.

Comment: @usr, would something like this be also relevant to you scenario? `var proxyTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Task<object>>(); proxyTcs.SetResult(faultedTask); await proxyTcs.Task.Unwrap();`

Comment: @Noseratio that works too, as I just tested. Preferring the cleaner SetException approach, though.

Comment: Indeed. I wasn't aware of that overload too, and I forgot the fact that `Task.Exception` is in fact `AggregateException`, so `Exception.InnerExceptions != null` always. What about stack traces, are they also nicely preserved this way?

Comment: @Noseratio stack trace is OK with both methods, Unwrap has one useless section in it.

Comment: For anyone else who arrived here due to .Result appearing to throw exceptions other than AggregateException -- note that ValueTask.Result behaves differently from Task.Result. Task.Result always wraps the exception as an AggregateException, while ValueTask.Result does not

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It turns out that await can throw AggregateException, though, which is not documented behavior.

No, that's the behaviour when the first nested exception *is* an `AggregateException`.

Basically, when you call `TaskCompletionSource.SetException(Exception)`, it wraps that exception in an `AggregateException`.

If you want to preserve *multiple* exceptions, just use the overload of `SetException` which accepts an `IEnumerable<Exception>`:

```
proxyTcs.SetException(faultedTask.Exception.InnerExceptions);
```